# How can I ban only one transitive dependency in my maven project?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

What I am trying currently is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <banTransitiveDependencies>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*:*:*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4</include>
                        </includes>
                    </banTransitiveDependencies>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My intention with what I try above is:

> Exclude banning all transitive dependencies, except commons-lang:2.4

When I try

```
mvn verify
```

I will get

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) @ ebtam-core ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

which is not good. Because I know I have the following dependency in my project:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I can't say for sure (which is why this is a comment, not an answer), but isn't it the other way around? You want to exclude commons-lang from the ban rule, but enforce that everything else is banned. So your *:*:* is included, and commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4 is excluded. That's the way I understood it from https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banTransitiveDependencies.html

Comment: @Creperum No, I want to exclude everything, include commons-lang.

Comment: If you like to ban the commons-lang dependency you only have to define the include as you already did but you have to remove the excludes.

Comment: @khmarbaise But include is only overriding the excludes, isn 't it?

Comment: Excludes has precedence....Usually you exclude particular artifacts/versions etc...

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not sure if I understand you but thanks for the comments.

Comment: Without <exclude>*</exclude> plugin (v3.3.0 in my case) bans any transitive dep. This is a fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see where this is documented but the problem is that the current build artifact is also considered when checking for the `banTransitiveDependencies` rules. Then, [looking at the code](https://github.com/apache/maven-enforcer/blob/enforcer-1.4.1/enforcer-rules/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/enforcer/BanTransitiveDependencies.java#L95), since this artifact is excluded, it won't check its dependencies. So when you specify `*` for the exclude pattern, the main artifact matches that and the rest of the includes rules are ignored. So the following would work:

```
<rules>
    <banTransitiveDependencies>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>commons-lang</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4</include>
        </includes>
    </banTransitiveDependencies>
</rules>
```

but it doesn't answer your question of "Exclude banning all transitive dependencies, except commons-lang:2.4".

The question is, why are you using this rule in the first place? It was introduced in [MENFORCER-138](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-138) and its goal is to force developers to not rely on transitive dependencies being inherited and force their declaration in the POM.

Your goal here is to fail the build if the dependency `commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4` is in the classpath. Therefore, you should use the [`bannedDependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) rule. By default, it searches dependencies transitively. The following will do what you want, i.e. ban only `commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4`:

```
<rules>
    <bannedDependencies>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </bannedDependencies>
</rules>
```

Comment: Well I simplified the situation a little, but thanks, this helps me a lot. I will try and accept the answer if it works for me (I believe it will).

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the link to plugin source code.

I solved the challenge with the rule

```
<rules>
  <bannedDependencies>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>groupId:artifactId</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </bannedDependencies>
</rules>
```

The output sample:

```
Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.BannedDependencies failed with message:
SOME_GAV:36.0.39-SNAPSHOT
   SOME_GAV:30.000.00.41
      groupId:artifactId:jar:7.1.11 <--- banned via the exclude/include list
```

Plugin version used: 3.4.1